# Разный результат компиляции кода на c++ на виртуальной машине с гостевой linux-системой под разными хост-системами (Ubuntu и Windows 10))

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, g++

Собираю большой С++-проект на виртуальной машине (VirtualBox) со специализированным дистрибутивом Linux (Astra Linux 1.6). На одном из моих компьютеров эта виртуальная машина работает под управлением Windows 10, а на другом компьютере точно такая же виртуальная машина - под управлением Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
Программа, собранная на компьютере с Windows, прекрасно работает на обоих компьютерах.
Тот же исходный код, собранный в идентичном окружении, но на компьютере с Ubuntu, при выполнении падает с ошибкой  Illegal instruction на обоих компьютерах.
Ошибка происходит при рекурсивном обращении к методу одного из моих классов уже на второй итерации. Просмотр стека на момент падения (использую valgrind) показывает, что при втором обращении к методу его адрес в стеке отличается на 1 байт от адреса первого обращения.
У меня есть подозрение, что компилятор g++ пытается как-то использовать особенности хостовой машины, которые не работают при исполнении программы в данной виртуальной среде.
Есть ли какие-нибудь опции компилятора, которые запретят ему такие попытки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если вы не включали эти опции (типа `-mtune=native`) самостоятельно, то попыток самостоятельно использовать особенности хостовой системы со стороны компилятора быть не должно. Однако весьма вероятно, что это просто ошибка в вашей программе.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно нашлась ошибка, приводящая к падению программы. Меня сбило с толку, что сборка компилятором той же версии, но на другой машине, оказалась не чувствительной к этой ошибке.